# If I execute a program via terminal it opens, but if I open it via .desktop file it doesn't

Tags: command-line, bash, .desktop, bashrc

I've installed Matlab inside /home/user/Desktop/matlabFolder/bin/ .

I can run Matlab running /home/user/Desktop/matlabFolder/bin/matlab inside a terminal, and it works.

I created a .desktop file here: /home/user/.local/share/applications/matlab.desktop and this is the content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MATLAB
Exec=/home/user/Desktop/matlabFolder/bin/matlab
Icon=/home/user/Pictures/Matlab_Logo.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development;Math;Science;Education;
```

If I search for MATLAB in application launcher, I find the icon and I can start it... I can see the Matlab logo that shows that it's starting but after some seconds the logo disappears and nothing happens.....
Why? How can I try to fix? Can it be something related to ambient variables and stuff like that?

Comment: Just an idea: What if you tried making it say Terminal=true? Also, the path /home/user/Desktop/matlabFolder/bin/matlab should have a file type at the end. Look at the file, and see what it is. It may be a .deb file, or something. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @Jeff "[...]/bin/matlab should have a file type at the end" — Not necessarily; actually, quite the contrary. Look into your `/usr/bin/` directory and see for yourself. Application executable files usually lack any file type extension.

Comment: @allexj what looks weird to me is that the `/home/<YourUserNameHere>/Desktop/matlabFolder/bin/[...]` path suggests that your entire application is hosted out of your `~/Desktop/` folder. That should not be the case. The `~/Desktop/` folder should contain only symlinks, and other lightweight stuff, I believe. You could put your `matlabFolder/` anywhere within your user's home: `~` (and then refer to that correctly in the `Exec` line of the .desktop file.

Comment: @Levente I don't think I have understood what you said :( why should it be a problem if matlab binaries are in a folder in the Desktop?

Comment: Weeeeellllll because on Windows,,, 10 years ago,,, it was the case thattttt...... Well, admittedly I took this idea out of my Windows Urban Legends shelf. But really, I seem to have heard that on Windows, files placed on the desktop were always loaded into memory upon every system start. So when people stuffed their desktops with actual heavy-weight documents, instead only with "shortcuts", all they achieved was overstuffing their RAM with a whole bunch of cruft that they did not intend to work with in the given session. And today I _presumed_ that it's the case for contemporary Ubuntu too.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `-desktop` at the end of `Exec=...` desktop-file field.

So the correct line will look like

```
Exec=/home/user/Desktop/matlabFolder/bin/matlab -desktop
```

Comment: doesn't work, just tried :(

Comment: worked for me! Thanks :)